# How to connect PHP to MySQL as an interactive connection is it will use interactive_timeout instead of wait_timeout?

Tags: php, mysql, timeout, mysql-connect, database-connection

So, MySQL has `wait_timeout` and `interactive_timeout`. By default, MySQL connections we make use `wait_timeout`. I want to use `interactive_timeout` for connection with users so the timeout won't disturb user interaction. How can I create an interactive connection?

My current code is this:

```
$db_conn = mysqli_connect(HOSTNAME, DBUSERNAME, DBPASSWORD,DATABASE);
```

Comment: How exactly do you intend to have a PHP script be interactive?

Comment: Why don't you increase the `wait_timeout` for the non interactive session?

Comment: Are you going to use it with a socket server such as ratchet or with a regular web-server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_interactive_timeout

"The number of seconds the server waits for activity on an interactive connection before closing it. An interactive client is defined as a client that uses the CLIENT_INTERACTIVE option to mysql_real_connect(). See also wait_timeout."

and, from PHP:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-connect.php

Answer (score 1):

Even if you had read the documentation, it is not really clear what `interactive_timeout` means.

It means if a connection of an interactive client is *idle* for too long, the connection is automatically closed. This won't disturb any user interaction, because if they are running queries, by definition the connection is not idle.

The default value of both `wait_timeout` and `interactive_timeout` is 28800 seconds (8 hours). So the client would have to be doing nothing but holding open the connection for 8 hours before it times out due to inactivity. This is very unlikely to affect any PHP request, which close as soon as the request is done.

It is also not mentioned in the documentation that the only existing client that uses `interactive_timeout` is the [mysql command-line client](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql.html).

All connectors for languages like PHP, Java, ODBC, Python, Perl, etc. use the regular `wait_timeout`. I have not seen any connector that has an option to use `interactive_timeout`. Programmatic connectors are not considered interactive, even though the application they are connecting from accepts user input.

Even the new MySQL Shell client does not enable `interactive_timeout`. It relies on the traditional `wait_timeout` that other clients use.